# how to convert in time format with regex in dart

Tags: regex, dart

I have a String  `[1: 3]` who can be also `[24: 59]`.
I have no problem with `[24: 59]` but I tried to convert `[1: 3]` to 01:03 currently I use regex to extract 1 and 3 with this code

```
   RegExp regExp = new RegExp(          
    r"(\d+), (\d+)",
  );

  var match = regExp.firstMatch(rappel1);
  group1rappel1 = match.group(1);
  group2rappel1 = match.group(2);
  prefs.setString('counter700',"$group1rappel1:$group2rappel1");
```

the result is `1:3`, I don't know how to add decimal.

Comment: Your first example had a space at the beginning and the end of the string. If they should be ignored then you might need to change the regex in my answer. Please make your question more clear what exactly your strings look like.

Comment: OK sorry, I'm using the package flutter_picker to select time (h:m) but currently the  output format is [X; X]  there is a space after ,  and X can only be 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 . I tried to convert to 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 to have a format like 24:24.

Comment: It's OK with  group1rappel1 =(match.group(1).padLeft(2, '0')); thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main() {
  final regExp = RegExp(r'\[\s*(\d{1,2})\:\s*(\d{1,2})\]');

  final match1 = regExp.firstMatch('[1: 3]');
  print(match1.group(1).padLeft(2, '0'));
  print(match1.group(2).padLeft(2, '0'));
  final match2 = regExp.firstMatch('[24: 59]');
  print(regExp.hasMatch('[24: 59]'));
  print(match2.group(1).padLeft(2, '0'));
  print(match2.group(2).padLeft(2, '0'));
}
```

If you want to support more than 2 digits you can use `\d+` instead of `\d{1,2}` (or `\d{1,5}`)